# How to add more Fields using Form Api

Tags: 7, forms

I want to add an add more button to an element in Drupal form (using Drupal Form API). Should I make it with javascript (append a new element) and check for `$_POST` in submission or is there another solution in Drupal API.

This is my code for that field, I want users to be able to upload more than one image:

```
$form['product'] = array(
  '#title' => t('product'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => variable_get('product', ''),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(0.6*1024*1024),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, there are several options. By "add more" do you mean to allow the user to add another value to a field (for example, to upload more than one file per Webform submission)?

Comment: It looks like you want to use "Number of value:" option. it comes by default and you can find it in the configuration page of your field.

Comment: @beth as you said to upload more than file using form api

Comment: @SydBarrett I want to make a form using form Api not a cck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Drupal's AJAX Form functionality](http://drupal.org/node/752056) to add elements to a form from the client.

If you try to update a Drupal form with JavaScript on the client side, it will not be submitted correctly. Drupal knows what was in the form when it was sent to the client, and expects that same structure to be sent back. Therefore, you need to use AJAX to tell Drupal the form is updated (with more fields, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can allow multiple file uploads per field with [the multiupload filefield widget module](http://drupal.org/project/1115362) and if you need image support, extend it with [the multiupload imagefield widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your *specific* need to do multiple uploading of images another option would be to use the [media gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module (which requires [media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module).